# linq item get without foreach in selected new keyword

Tags: c#, linq

i wants to get a data using linq to SQL. I used for each like this
is there is another way to get query data without for each .basically i wants to get d.name from query without using for each loop because i know there is one object no need to used loop for it.

```
var query=from d in db.table where d.id=2 select new {d.name};
foreach (var item in query)
        {
            string a=item.name;
        }
```

Comment: If you know there is one and only one item, then you can use `SingleOrDefault`. If there may be more than one, and you just want the first, then use `FirstOrDefault`. And you should remove your earlier comment - that language won't get you far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want only the first name, you don't need an anoymous type here, you can just use `FirstOrDefault` like this:

```
db.table.Where(d => d.id == 2).Select(d => d.name).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return the name of the first record with `id` 2 or return *null* if there is no such record.

If you want all names use `ToList` instead of `FirstOrDefault`

Answer (score 0):

You can use FirstOrDefault with your code like this (if `d.name` is a string):

```
var query=(from d in db.table
           where d.id==2 
           select d.name)
           .FirstOrDefault();
```